# CUDA Matrix Addition Execution Time with Variation in Block and Grid Dimensions

Tags: cuda

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <malloc.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t rdtsc()
{
    return __rdtsc();
}


void init_matrix(int *a,int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        a[i]=i;
}

void print_matrix(int *a,int rows,int columns)
{

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
            printf("%d  ",a[j+i*columns]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


}
__global__ void add_matrix(int *c,int *a,int *b,int rows,int columns)
{
    //printf("Thread Launched %d\n",threadIdx.x);
    int x = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    int y= threadIdx.y+blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
    int i=x+y*columns;

    c[i]=a[i]+b[i];
}

int main()
{

    int rows=1<<10,columns=1<<10;
    int *h_a,*h_b,*h_c;
    int blockx=512,blocky=512;
    int num_bytes=rows*columns*sizeof(int);
    h_a=(int *)malloc(num_bytes);
    h_b=(int *)malloc(num_bytes);

    h_c=(int *)malloc(num_bytes);


    init_matrix(h_a,rows*columns);
    init_matrix(h_b,rows*columns);


    int *d_a,*d_b,*d_c;

    dim3 block(blockx,blocky);
    dim3 grid(rows/block.x,columns/block.x);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, num_bytes);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b, num_bytes);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_c, num_bytes);

cudaMemcpy(d_a,h_a,num_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_b,h_b,num_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

unsigned __int64 a,b;

a=rdtsc();
add_matrix<<<grid,block>>>(d_c,d_a,d_b,rows,columns);
b=rdtsc();





printf("Cycles Taken=%d\n",b-a);

cudaDeviceSynchronize();
cudaMemcpy(h_c,d_c,num_bytes,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);








   system("pause");
cudaFree(d_a);
cudaFree(d_b);
cudaFree(d_c);
free(h_a);
free(h_b);
free(h_c);
cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

Above is a matrix addition kernel which I am using to determine the execution time of the kernel on GPU in Cycles.

blockx=1,blocky=1        Cycles = 436343455

blockx=4,blocky=4        Cycles = 32447213

blockx=32,blocky=32      Cycles= 8421874

blockx=128,blocky=128    Cycles =71655

blockx=256,blocky=256    Cycles =73000

blockx=512, blocky=512   Cycles 70002

The above shows the number of cycles the kernel took with changing block.x and block.y dimensions. The execution time is much less in case of  relatively larger block dimensions. Can anybody explain me why is it so. Is it because of the reason that warps do not get utilized properly?

P.S- These results are from an ASUS ROG laptop having i7-4710HQ and GTX 860M.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) 3 or 4 issues:

1. CUDA threadblocks are limited to 1024 threads *total*.  That means the product of block.x * block.y * block.z must be less than or equal to 1024.  So your block dimensions above 32x32 are simply failing to run the kernel at all.  You have no indication of this because you are not doing [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).
2. For block sizes 32x32 and smaller, in general the GPU likes to have a lot of work.  Threadblocks should have a minimum of about 128 threads (4 warps) if you want to have a chance to fully utilize the GPU. (And you should use many threadblocks, probably at least 64.)  This relates to latency hiding.
3. Below 32 threads in a block (2 of your cases), you also have the issue that you are scheduling work on 32 execution units, but some are idle, since the GPU only schedules work in the unit of a warp (32 threads).
4. This kind of host-based timing methodology around kernel calls:

   ```
   a=rdtsc();
   add_matrix<<<grid,block>>>(d_c,d_a,d_b,rows,columns);
   b=rdtsc();
   ```

   is usually troublesome because kernel calls are *asynchronous* meaning control is returned to the CPU thread immediately, before the kernel has finished executing.  Moving your device synchronize inside the timing region:

   ```
   a=rdtsc();
   add_matrix<<<grid,block>>>(d_c,d_a,d_b,rows,columns);
   cudaDeviceSynchronize();
   b=rdtsc();
   ```

   is usually preferred.  (However, the numbers you are seeing may be plausible.)

If you want to learn more about the issues related to 2 and 3 above, I suggest you review a basic presentation on first-level GPU optimizations, such as [this one](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0514-GTC2012-GPU-Performance-Analysis.pdf)